# ¿Cómo saber qué versión de C++ estoy usando?

Tags: c++, compilador

Estoy usando *Embarcadero RAD Studio 2010* y quisiera saber qué versión de *C++* usa, tengo entendido que la última versión actual es la *14* pero quiero saber la versión que estoy usando y si puedo modificarla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo RAD studio utiliza su propio compilador, puedes ver sus características [aquí](https://www.embarcadero.com/free-tools/ccompiler). Tal parece (según las características descritas en su sitio web) que la version que utiliza es C11.

Respecto a si es posible cambiarla... Lo dudo, RAD necesita de su propio compilador para funcionar por que esta destinado para el CROSS-PLATFORM y por lo tanto no debería ser compatible con Compiladores genéricos como los de [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org).

Comment: Eh usado este código para saber si el Rad studio 2010 que tengo usa la versión c++11 :  if( __cplusplus == 201103L ) std::cout << "C++11\n" ;
           else if( __cplusplus == 199711L ) std::cout << "C++98\n" ;
            else std::cout << "pre-standard C++\n" ; y me sale que no. entonces como puedo "actualizarla" si es posible o hacer que la use.

Comment: Es importante que entiendas que al ser un software para exportar aplicaciones multiplataforma este no tiene que estar apegado al standard de C++ y probablemente tenga varios cambios en la generación de su código objeto, RAD  trabaja tal cual como te lo presentas no puedes cambiarle la version de C++.

Comment: Si lo que buscas es programa en C++ para computadoras te recomiendo que utilices algún IDE para ese propósito, ellos normalmente te dan la opción de bajo que compilador trabajar (y por ende cual version de c++ utilizar) ahora si lo que quieres es utilizarlo para desarrollar apps moviles no te queda otra que apegarte a lo que te ofrece el programa

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. No me queda de otra que usar otra IDE para poder usar c++11 .