# ¿Cómo saber la versión del estándar C que estoy utilizando en código?

Tags: c++, c, estándares

He visto un relacionado [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/57777/c%C3%B3mo-saber-qu%C3%A9-versi%C3%B3n-de-c-estoy-usando), pero no es la misma respuesta.

Así como dice el título, muchos sabemos que la diferencia *(Tanto en características como sintaxis)* entre estándares es bastante grande, el ANSI C (C89, C90) no permitía muchas cosas de las que C99 en adelante permite, tal como la definición de un tipo en su declaración o la definición de una variable en un ciclo ... *¡Incluso los comentarios de una línea!*

La pregunta surge al tener que realizar código que funcione bajo todos los estándares de C:

- ANSI C (C89 & C90)
- C94
- C99
- C11

Debido a que no puedo utilizar el tipo `long long` y a ciertas plataformas de 8 y 16 bits que no permiten ciertos valores provocando *[integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)*, de igual forma el compilador de poseen estas plataformas es de cuando K&R *(1972+)*, otras son del año 1990, por lo que no tengo las nuevas funcionalidades.

Comment: ¿No debería esta pregunta tener también la etiqueta C++?

Comment: No estaría de más agregarla, creo que se puede considerar para ambos lenguajes.

Comment: Lo he comentado porque en la respuesta tratas también las opciones de C++ y me daba la sensación de que si no se quedaba un poco huérfana

Comment: Ah, mi problema es específico de C, pero no está mal ponerlo, pues tambien ofrece soluciones para C++.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

La mejor forma de saber cuál es la versión del estándar con la que se está compilando, es utilizando la macro de preprocesador: `__STDC_VERSION__`, la cual está disponible a partir de C99 y su valor se carga con las siguientes versiones:

- `__STDC_VERSION__ == 199409L` el estándar es `C94`<sup>1</sup>.
- `__STDC_VERSION__ == 199901L` el estándar es `C99`.
- `__STDC_VERSION__ == 201112L` es estándar es `C11`.

Para otros estándares, se definen las macros de preprocesador:

- `__ANSI__` para ANSI C (C89 y C90)
- `__STDC__` de igual forma para ANSI C<sup>2</sup>.

> Cabe mencionar que `__STDC_VERSION__` no se define al utilizar estándares de `GNU C`, pasa lo mismo al utilizar un compilador de C++.

Una lista de los estándares hasta la fecha del 2014 se puede encontrar:

```
Versión     Macro               Estándar
---------------------------------------------------
C89         __STDC__            ANSI X3.159-1989
C90         __STDC__            ISO/IEC 9899:1990
C94         __STDC_VERSION__    ISO/IEC 9899-1:1994
C99         __STDC_VERSION__    ISO/IEC 9899:1999
C11         __STDC_VERSION__    ISO/IEC 9899:2011
C++98       __cplusplus         ISO/IEC 14882:1998
C++11       __cplusplus         ISO/IEC 14882:2011
C++14       __cplusplus         ISO/IEC 14882:2014
C++/CLI     __cplusplus_cli     ECMA-372
...
```

Probar el siguiente programa en forma de ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {
    #ifdef __STDC_VERSION__
        printf("Aparentemente compatible con __STDC_VERSION__\n");
    #   if __STDC_VERSION__ == 199901L
        printf("Este código fue compilando con el estandar C99.\n");
    #   elif __STDC_VERSION__ == 201112L
        printf("Este codigo fue compilado con el estandar C11.\n");
    #   else
        printf("Este codigo fue compilado con el estandar C94.\n");
    #   endif /* == */
    #endif /* __STDC_VERSION__ */


    #ifdef __cplusplus
        printf("Aparentemente compilado con un compilador de C++\n");
    #   if __cplusplus >= 201103L
        printf("Este codigo fue compilado bajo un estandar mayor o igual a C++11.\n");
    #   else
        printf("Este codigo fue compilado bajo un estandar menor a C++11.");
    #   endif /* >= */
    #endif /* __cplusplus */

    #ifdef __STDC__
        printf("Aparentemente compatible con __STDC__ y los estandares C89 y C90 ...\n");
    #endif /* __STDC__ */
}
```

Al ejecutarlo bajo el estándar C99:

> `gcc -o test -std=c99 test.c`

Obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
Aparentemente compatible con __STDC_VERSION__
Este código fue compilando con el estandar C99.
Aparentemente compatible con __STDC__ y los estandares C89 y C90
```

Y si lo compilo con un compilador de C++ bajo el estándar C11:

> `g++ -o test -std=c++11 test.c`

Se puede obtener el siguiente resultado:

```
Aparentemente compilado con un compilador de C++
Este codigo fue compilado bajo un estandar mayor o igual a C++11.
Aparentemente compatible con __STDC__ y los estandares C89 y C90 ...
```

Usando ese código se puede saber cuál estándar está compilando actualmente, incluso con cuál compilador *(No su nombre, pero sí el lenguaje)*.

<sup>1</sup>: Este estándar no es soportado por `gcc`.
<sup>2</sup>: Esta macro se define en todos los estándares con el valor de `1`, pero su comportamiento puede variar por compilador, así que no es totalmente confiable, a menos que se desee saber si se está compilando con un compilador de C, en un compilador de C++ no arrojaría su definición.

Referencias:

1. [The C Preprocessor (gcc.gnu.org)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html#Standard-Predefined-Macros)
2. [Pre-defined Compiler Macros](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Standards/)

Answer (score 5):

Como información complementaria me gustaría añadir las macros de presencia de característica de C++.

#### Un breve inciso de historia.

El estándar de C++ de 2011 (inicialmente conocido como C++0x y luego conocido como C++11) fue el estándar que más tardó en ser aprobado (el estándar anterior era de 1998<sup>1</sup>).

C++11 añadió al lenguaje C++ muchas características nuevas, tantas que hacía que C++ pareciese un lenguaje nuevo. Dada la gran cantidad de características a implementar por parte de los desarrolladores de compiladores, la adhesión al estándar C++11 fue irregular e incompleta entre compiladores durante mucho tiempo.

Esto hizo que fuera necesario poder comprobar características individuales del lenguaje en lugar de comprobar estándares (ya que el compilador podía decir ser C++11 pero carecer de algunas características de C++11); para hacer esto posible, se crearon las macros de presencia de característica.

#### Macros de presencia de característica.

Las macros de presencia de característica permiten comprobar si una característica de C++ en concreto está implementada en el compilador de C++ en curso.

Las características se dividen en características de librería y características de lenguaje, así pues las macros siguen el formato:

> - Características de lenguaje: `__cpp_`*`nombre_de_la_característica`*.
> - Características de librería: `__cpp_lib_`*`nombre_de_la_característica`*.

#### Listado de macros de características.

C++17

- `__cpp_noexcept_function_type`: Hacer las especificaciones de excpepción parte de la firma de la función. [P0012R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0012r1.html).
- `__cpp_fold_expressions`: Expresiones agrupables. [N4191](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4191.html), [N4295](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4295.html).
- `__cpp_static_assert`: Extensión de `static_assert`. [N3928](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3928.pdf).
- `__cpp_namespace_attributes`: Atributos para espacios de nombres. [N4196](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4196.html), [N4266](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4266.html).
- `__cpp_enumerator_attributes`: Atributos para enumerados.
- `__cpp_nested_namespace_definitions`: Definiciones anidadas de espacios de nombres. [N4230](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4230.html).
- `__cpp_inheriting_constructors`: Extensión de constructores heredados. [P0136R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0136r0.html), [P0136R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0136r1.html).
- `__cpp_nontype_template_args`: Permitir la evaluación constante de parámetros de plantilla no-tipo. [N4198](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4198.html), [N4268](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4268.html).
- `__cpp_lib_uncaught_exceptions`: Utilidad `std::uncaught_exceptions`. [N4152](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4152.pdf), [N4259](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4259.pdf).
- `__cpp_lib_as_const`: Utilidad `std::as_const`. [P0007R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0007r1.html).
- `__cpp_lib_transparent_operators`: Operadores transparentes (flexibilizar `std::owner_less`). [P0074R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0074r0.html).
- `__cpp_lib_invoke`: Utilidad `std::invoke`. [N4169](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4169.html).
- `__cpp_lib_void_t`: Utilidad `std::void_t`. [N3911](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3911.pdf).
- `__cpp_lib_bool_constant`: Utilidad `std::bool_constant`. [N4389]8http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4389.html).
- `__cpp_lib_type_trait_variable_templates`: Utilidad `std::is_void_v`. [P0006R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0006r0.html).
- `__cpp_lib_logical_traits`: Rasgos lógicos. [P0013R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0013r1.html).
- `__cpp_lib_chrono`: Funciones de redondeo para `std::chrono::duration` y `std::chrono::time_point`. [P0092R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0092r1.html).
- `__cpp_lib_allocator_traits_is_always_equal`: Limpieza de la librería estandar, eliminación de `noexcept`. [N4258](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4258.pdf).
- `__cpp_lib_incomplete_container_elements`: Tipos incompletos para contenedores estándar. [N4510](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4510.html).
- `__cpp_lib_map_try_emplace`, `__cpp_lib_map_try_emplace`, `__cpp_lib_unordered_map_try_emplace`: Mejoras en la interfaz de inserción en `std::map::try_emplace`, `std::map::insert_or_assign` y sus equivalentes en `std::unordered_map`. [N4279](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4279.html).
- `__cpp_lib_nonmember_container_access`: Acceso uniforme a utilidades de contenedor mediante funciones libres. [N4280](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4280.pdf).
- `__cpp_lib_shared_mutex`: Mutex compartido sin límite de tiempo. [N4508](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4508.html).
- `__cpp_lib_lock_guard_variadic`: Utilidad `std::lock_guard` variádica. [P0156R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0156r0.html).

C++14

- `__cpp_binary_literals`: Literales binarios. [N3472](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3472.pdf).
- `__cpp_init_captures`: Capturas generalizadas en lambdas. [N3610](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3610.html), [N3648](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3648.html).
- `__cpp_generic_lambdas`: Lambdas genéricas. [N3649](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3649.html).
- `__cpp_sized_deallocation`: Operador `delete` con tamaño. [N3778](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3778.html).
- `__cpp_constexpr`: Relajar las limitaciones de `constexpr`. [N3652](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3652.html).
- `__cpp_decltype_auto`, `__cpp_return_type_deduction`: Deducción del tipo de retorno en funciones. [N3638](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html).
- `__cpp_aggregate_nsdmi`: Inicializadores de miembros en agregados. [N3653](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3653.html).
- `__cpp_variable_templates`: Variables plantilla. [N3651](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3651.pdf).
- `__cpp_lib_integer_sequence`: Utilidad `std::integer_sequence`. [N3658](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3658.html).
- `__cpp_lib_exchange_function`: Utilidad `std::exchange()`. [N3668](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3668.html).
- `__cpp_lib_tuples_by_type`: Acceder a miembros de tupla mediante el tipo. [N3670](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3670.html).
- `__cpp_lib_tuple_element_t`: Utilidad `std::tuple_element_t`. [N3887](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3887.pdf).
- `__cpp_lib_make_unique`: Utilidad `std::make_unique`. [N3656](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3656.htm).
- `__cpp_lib_transparent_operators`: Operadores transparentes (flexibilizar `std::greater`). [N3421](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3421.htm).
- `__cpp_lib_integral_constant_callable`: Operador de llamada en `std::integral_constant`. [N3545](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3545.pdf).
- `__cpp_lib_transformation_trait_aliases`: Utilidades en los rasgos de transformación. [N3655](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3655.pdf).
- `__cpp_lib_result_of_sfinae`: Ayudas a la técnica [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error). [N3462](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3462.html).
- `__cpp_lib_is_final`: Utilidad `std::is_final`. [LWG 2112](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3945.html#2112).
- `__cpp_lib_is_null_pointer`: Utilidad `std::is_null_pointer`. [LWG 2247](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3822.html#2247).
- `__cpp_lib_chrono_udls`, `__cpp_lib_string_udls`: Literales definidos por el usuario para tipos de las cabeceras `<chrono>` y `<string>`. [N3642](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3642.pdf).
- `__cpp_lib_generic_associative_lookup`: Comparaciones heterogéneas en contenedores asociativos. [N3657](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3657.htm).
- `__cpp_lib_null_iterators`: Iteradores nulos. [N3644](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3644.pdf).
- `__cpp_lib_make_reverse_iterator`: Utilidad `std::make_reverse_iterator`. [LWG 2285](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3945.html#2285).
- `__cpp_lib_robust_nonmodifying_seq_ops`: Dotar de mayor robustez las operaciones sobre secuencia que no modifican la misma (`std::mismatch`, `std::equal` y `std::is_permutation}`). [N3671](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3671.html).
- `__cpp_lib_complex_udls`: Literales definidos por el usuario para el tipo `std::complex`. [N3779](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3779.pdf).
- `__cpp_lib_quoted_string_io`: Utilidad `std::quoted`. [N3654](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3654.html).
- `__cpp_lib_shared_timed_mutex`: Utilidad `std::shared_timed_mutex`. [N3891](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3891.htm).

C++11

- `__cpp_unicode_characters`, `__cpp_raw_strings`, `__cpp_unicode_literals`: Texto unicode y en crudo. [N2249](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2249.html). [N2442](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2442.htm).
- `__cpp_user_defined_literals`: Literales definidos por el usuario. [N2765](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2765.pdf).
- `__cpp_lambdas`: Lambdas. [N2927](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2927.pdf).
- `__cpp_constexpr`: Expresiones constantes. [N2235](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2235.pdf).
- `__cpp_range_based_for`: Bucle `for` de rango. [N2930](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2930.html).
- `__cpp_static_assert`: Aserciones estáticas. [N1720](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1720.html).
- `__cpp_decltype`: Operador de consulta de tipo `decltype`. [N2343](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2343.pdf).
- `__cpp_attributes`: Atributos C++. [N2761](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2761.pdf).
- `__cpp_rvalue_references`: Referencias a valores del lado derecho. [N2118](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2118.html).
- `__cpp_variadic_templates`: Plantillas variadicas. [N2242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2242.pdf).
- `__cpp_initializer_lists`: Listas de inicialización. [N2672](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2672.htm).
- `__cpp_explicit_conversion`: Operadores explícitos de conversión. [N2437](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2437.pdf).
- `__cpp_delegating_constructors`: Constructores delegados. [N1986](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1986.pdf).
- `__cpp_nsdmi`: Inicialización de datos miembro no estáticos. [N2756](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2756.htm).
- `__cpp_inheriting_constructors`: Constructores heredados. [N2540](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2540.htm).
- `__cpp_ref_qualifiers`: Cualificadores de referencia. [N2439](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2439.htm).
- `__cpp_alias_templates`: Alias de plantilla. [N2258](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2258.pdf).

---

<sup>1</sup>Existe un estándar *no oficial* en 2003 conocido como C++03 que en realidad no era estándar *per se* si no una colección de especificaciones técnicas.

Comment: Hermoso, simplemente hermoso ❤

Comment: Discrepo, horrible, tremendamente horrible por la incapacidad de la red SE de generar **TABLAS**. Todo esto en una tabla quedaría mejor.

Comment: ¡Pero bueno, calma! Que en algún momento lo tendremos.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster ¿que significa red SE?

Comment: @KeineLust SE serían las siglas de StackExchange. La red StackExchange está formada por las páginas como esta (StackOverflow en Español, SEes) o el StackOverflow original (SOen). Puedes ver todas las páginas de la red SE [aquí](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster vale! creía que te referías a que el preprocesador pudiera generar la información de los `__cpp_`* ... en una tabla (clave - valor) en forma de array 2D y no le veía sentido.