# ¿Qué es SFINAE?

Tags: c++, sfinae

He visto en varias preguntas mencionada la palabra SFINAE, no sé si se es todo en mayúsculas o como un nombre propio: Sfinae.

[Buscando en Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=sfinae) me encuentro que incluso hay documentos estándar que hacen referencia a este término, como el [n3462](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3462.html) mencionado en [¿Cómo saber la versión del estándar C que estoy utilizando en código?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68937/c%c3%b3mo-saber-la-versi%c3%b3n-del-est%c3%a1ndar-c-que-estoy-utilizando-en-c%c3%b3digo), pero por mucho que busco no veo que se trate de una librería ni una clase. Así que me pregunto:

#### ¿Qué es SFINAE?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Para empezar, SFINAE es un acrónimo de:

> **S**ubstitution **F**ailure **I**s **N**ot **A**n **E**rror.

Podría traducirse como FESNEUE o FASNEUE:

> **F**allo **E**n **S**ubstitución **N**o **E**s **U**n **E**rror.
>
> **F**allo **A**l **S**ubstituir **N**o **E**s **U**n **E**rror.

Para la [RAE](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-de-la-lengua-espanola/que-contiene/item-numero-2#_Toc85519273) un acrónimo se escribe en mayúsculas si es necesario deletrearlo:

> #### 2.7. Siglas y acrónimos
>
> Las siglas y acrónimos cuya frecuencia de uso les ha dado un carácter gramatical definido -sustantivos masculinos o femeninos, por ejemplo-, aparecen recogidos como entradas normales (p. ej., **radar),** o en letras mayúsculas cuando, por regla general, es necesario deletrearlos **(ADN).**

Dado que se puede leer con normalidad (incluso la versión Inglesa) yo (personalmente) lo escribiría como si fuese una palabra normal, así que vamos a reponder a la pregunta...

### ¿Qué es sfinae (fesneue/fasneue)?

Es una característica *curiosa* del funcionamiento de las plantillas (`template`) de C++. Esta característica nos dice que **fallar** al **substituir** un parámetro de plantilla **no tiene por qué ser un error**.

Para entender este funcionamiento, podemos ver qué pasa con una sencilla plantilla:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T plantilla(U u) { return static_cast<T>(u); }
```

Cuando usamos la plantilla anterior, la plantilla pasa por un proceso de [instanciación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instancia_(inform%C3%A1tica)), uno de los primeros pasos es substituir los parámetros genéricos (`T` y `U` en el ejemplo) por los parámetros proporcionados (o deducidos):

#### Substituir.

```
std::cout << plantilla<int, float>(123.456) << '\n';
```

En esta instanciación de `plantilla` se crea una función como esta:

```
   int plantilla(float u) { return static_cast<int>(u); }
// ^^^           ^^^^^                         ^^^
//  T              U                            T
```

El parámetro genérico `T` ha sido substituido por `int` mientras que `U` ha sido substituido por `float` e imprimirá `123` por consola.

#### ¡Fallar!.

Si cambiamos `plantilla` de la siguiente manera:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T plantilla(typename U::value_type u) { return static_cast<T>(u); }
//          ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- referencia sub-tipo en U
```

Al hacer la llamada anterior la substitución resultante será:

```
   int plantilla(typename float::value_type u) { return static_cast<int>(u); }
// ^^^                    ^^^^^                                     ^^^
//  T                       U                                        T
```

Dado que el tipo `float` no dispone de un sub-tipo `value_type`, la substitución falla y produce un error.

#### ¡No fallar!.

Pero si tuviéramos ambas funciones:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T plantilla(typename U::value_type u) { return static_cast<T>(u); }

template <typename T, typename U>
T plantilla(U u) { return static_cast<T>(u); }
```

Al instanciar la plantilla tendríamos una versión que falla y otra que no:

```
std::cout << plantilla<int, float>(123.456) << '\n';

// Fallo!
int plantilla(typename float::value_type u) { return static_cast<int>(u); }
// Correcto!
int plantilla(float u) { return static_cast<int>(u); }
```

En este caso, el compilador instancia todas las plantillas e intenta substituir todos los parámetros, si tras la substitución hay una (y solo una) versión válida de la plantilla entonces no producirá un error.

Es decir, en este caso hemos podido ver que un **F**allo **A**l **S**ubstituir **N**o **E**s **U**n **E**rror.

### Vale, lo he entendido pero... ¿para qué sirve?

El comportamiento del fasneue, forma parte de la naturaleza de las plantillas de C++. Las plantillas se diseñaron de esta manera para resolver otros problemas (como generar errores inesperados al incluir plantillas de librerías de terceros) pero algunos programadores C++ vieron un potencial adicional a este comportamiento, ya que permite una rudimentaria introspección de tipos en tiempo de compilación.

Por ejemplo, si tenemos una función que queremos que actúe de manera diferente según si se llama con números enteros o con números en coma flotante:

```
void f(int)   { std::cout << "int\n"; }
void f(float) { std::cout << "float\n"; }
```

Al llamarla con un tipo que no sea `int` o `float` fallaría por ambigüedad:

```
f(1u); // ERROR! Convierto unsigned int a int o a float?
f(.1); // ERROR! Convierto double a int o a float?
```

Una posible solución sería crear sobrecargas para todos los tipos:

```
void f(char)               { std::cout << "entero\n"; }
void f(unsigned char)      { std::cout << "entero\n"; }
void f(signed char)        { std::cout << "entero\n"; }
void f(short)              { std::cout << "entero\n"; }
void f(unsigned short)     { std::cout << "entero\n"; }
void f(int)                { std::cout << "entero\n"; }
void f(unsigned int)       { std::cout << "entero\n"; }
void f(long)               { std::cout << "entero\n"; }
void f(unsigned long)      { std::cout << "entero\n"; }
void f(long long)          { std::cout << "entero\n"; }
void f(unsigned long long) { std::cout << "entero\n"; }
void f(float)              { std::cout << "flotante\n"; }
void f(double)             { std::cout << "flotante\n"; }
void f(long double)        { std::cout << "flotante\n"; }
```

Es un engorro crear 14 funciones casi todas iguales con código repetido, pero con fesneue podemos separar estas funciones en entero y flotante:

```
template<class T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>* = nullptr>
void f(T) { std::cout << "entero\n"; }
template<class T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>* = nullptr>
void f(T) { std::cout << "flotante\n"; }
```

Las dos funciones plantilla anteriores permiten discernir si el tipo recibido es un valor entero o en coma flotante con tan sólo dos versiones de la función, se ayuda de otras plantillas para conseguirlo:

#### Características de tipo [`<type_traits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits).

Esta librería ofrece plantillas que permiten interrogar a los tipos para averiguar si cumplen con ciertas características, a parte de las "*¿El tipo es entero?*" y "*¿El tipo es coma flotante?*" que ya hemos visto, puede ser usada para comprobar si el tipo es un puntero, una clase o una función. Todas estas plantillas llamadas `is_xxxx` resultan en un valor booleano (calculado en tiempo de compilación) con valor verdadero si se cumple la verificación.

#### Condicional fesneue [`<std::enable_if>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)

La plantilla `std::enable_if` es un objeto que, en caso de cumplirse la condición recibida como primer parámetro, contendrá el tipo facilitado como segundo parámetro de plantilla; en caso contrario será un objeto vacío.

---

Sabiendo esto, el último ejemplo funcionaría de la siguiente manera:

```
template<class T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>* = nullptr>
void f(T) { std::cout << "entero\n"; }
template<class T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>* = nullptr>
void f(T) { std::cout << "flotante\n"; }

f(1u); // Muestra 'entero'
f(.1); // Muestra 'flotante'
```

En la fase de substitución, usando el literal de entero sin signo sucedería lo siguiente:

- `std::is_integral_v<unsigned int>` se substituye por `true`.
- `std::enable_if_t<unsigned int, true>` se substituye por `unsigned int`.
- La función `f` queda como `f(unsigned int)`.
- `std::is_floating_point_v<double>` se substituye por `false`.
- `std::enable_if_t<double, false>` se substituye por nada.
- La substitución falla.
- Se escoge la primera versión de la función como válida.

En el segundo caso, la substitución que falla es la primera y se escoge la segunda versión de la función `f` que no ha fallado en la substitución.