# Templates para datos diferentes en C++

Tags: c++, template

Estoy utilizando templates en C++ y soy nueva en esto por lo que no acabo de entender la forma de "reutilizar" las funciones independientemente del tipo de dato.

Dispongo del código mostrado a continuación:

```
template<typename T>
const T &min(const T &a, const T &b)
{
  if ( a < b )
        return a;
  else  return b;
}
```

Gracias a este código es posible utilizarlo para tipos de datos diferentes:

```
int main()
{
    cout << min( 7, 8 ) << endl;
    cout << min( string( "hola" ), string( "adiós") ) << endl;
}
```

Sin embargo, los tipos de datos tienen que ser iguales...
¿Cómo habría que cambiar el código para que funcionase lo siguiente (da un error al compilar)?

```
int main()
{
    cout << min( 7, string( "hola" ) ) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para que una plantilla (`template`) reciba dos tipos de datos diferentes, debes indicarle que puede trabajar con dos tipos diferentes:

```
template <typename primer_tipo, typename segundo_tipo>
???? min(const primer_tipo &p, const segundo_tipo &s)
{
    if ( p < s )
        return p;
    else  return s;
}
```

Pero esto nos trae un problema ¿cuál de los dos tipos debe devolver la función? La respuesta obvia es "*el tipo del valor que fuese menor*", pero no existe ningún mecanismo en C++ para hacer que una función pueda devolver dos tipos diferentes.

Sin embargo podemos usar una [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant):

```
template <typename primer_tipo, typename segundo_tipo>
std::variant<primer_tipo, segundo_tipo> min(const primer_tipo &p, const segundo_tipo &s)
{
    if ( p < s )
        return p;
    else  return s;
}
```

La `std::variant` es un tipo de datos que puede contener uno de los datos del tipo con que se la defina. Pero eso no significa que el código vaya a funcionar, significa que la función `min` podrá aceptar dos tipos diferentes. Si hacemos la llamada que propones:

```
min( 7, string( "hola" ) )
```

El código no compilará porque no existe un operador menor que (`<`) que compare enteros con cadenas, por suerte podemos definir uno:

```
bool operator<(const int &i, const std::string &s)
{
    return i < s.length();
}
```

De esta manera, el siguiente código:

```
auto m1 = min(7, std::string{"hola"});
auto m2 = min(10, std::string{"patatas fritas con ketchup y mayonesa"});
```

En `m1` tendremos `"hola"` y en `m2` tendremos `10`. Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nWais4MnI2mkqr6R)</kbd>.

> El operador que defines se hace para operar con un dato de tipo `int` y otro string, pero ¿Cómo se podría hacer para dos tipos `int`, para dos tipos `string`? ¿Habría que repetir el código para cada uno o se puede hacer de forma genérica?

No se pueden sobrecargar operadores para [tipos fundamentales](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) así que no se podrá crear un operador de comparación para dos `int`, en cuanto al operador de comparación de dos `string`, éste [ya existe](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp). Si quieres generalizar la comparación "*valor escalar*" contra "*cadena*" debemos usar de nuevo plantillas:

```
template <typename escalar>
bool operator<(const escalar &e, const std::string &s)
{
    static_assert(is_scalar_v<escalar>, "Debe ser un escalar!");
    const auto length = s.length();
    return static_cast<decltype(length)>(e) < length;
}
```

El operador anterior funcionará siempre que compares un escalar (números) contra un `std::string`, pero sólo funciona con un tipo de cadena de caracteres, podemos ir un paso más allá:

```
template <typename escalar, typename caracter>
bool operator<(const escalar &e, const std::basic_string<caracter> &s)
{
    static_assert(std::is_scalar_v<escalar>, "Debe ser un escalar!");
    const auto length = s.length();
    return static_cast<decltype(length)>(e) < length;
}
```

Con este cambio podrás comparar cualquier escalar con cualquier tipo de cadena (`std::string`, `std::wstring`, `std::u16string`, ... ), si comparas un dato no escalar con una cadena dará un fallo de compilación con el mensaje:

> ```
> static assertion failed: Debe ser un escalar!
> ```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HPhkDyB7z6zYdwgT)</kbd>.

Comment: Los test que se hacen para comprobar si es un escalar o no, ¿se podría hacer con SFINAE, es decir con enable_if...?

Comment: @adamista Si, se podría hacer con [SFINAE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/83319/2742), pero con `static_assert` se consigue el mismo resultado (fallo cuando el tipo no es adecuado) con menos código.

Comment: Pero por lo que tengo entendido, de esta manera se entraría en el método del operador y con SFINAE si se chequease el argumento que se pasa como parámetro ya no entraría en el operador. ¿es esto correcto?

Comment: @adamista No es correcto. SFINAE nos permite personalizar el comportamiento de una plantilla en base a sus parámetros pero **siempre** debe haber una (y sólo una) substitución de parámetro o en caso contrario sí que se desemboca en un error de compilación (bastante críptico además). Aplicar SFINAE en este caso nos permitiría seleccionar entre escalar y no-escalar; dado que (aparentemente) sólo queremos el comportamiento para escalar, deberíamos provocar un error en la rama SFINAE que da lugar a no-escalar.

Comment: Ok, gracias. Entendido

Answer (score 4):

> ¿Cómo habría que cambiar el código para que funcionase lo siguiente (da un error al compilar)?

Si en la plantilla únicamente defines un tipo (en este caso `T`):

```
template<typename T> 
const T &min(const T &a, const T &b)
{
  if ( a < b )
        return a;
  else  return b;
}
```

Esa `T` solo podrá ser sustituída por un único tipo, como por ejemplo `int`:

```
const int &min(const int &a, const int &b)
{
  if ( a < b )
        return a;
  else  return b;
}
```

Si necesitas que la función use dos tipos diferentes debes declarar dos tipos distintos:

```
template<class T, class U> 
const /* ¿? */ &min(const T &a, const U &b)
{
  return (a < b)? a : b;
}
```

Ahora, para que compile correctamente solo necesitas que exista un operador de comparación `<` entre los dos tipos que vayas a usar... Pero aquí nos encontramos con otro problema y es... ¿qué devolvemos aquí? Yo he asumido que se devuelve el tipo `T` pero... ¿Qué sucede si se necesita devolver `b` que es de tipo `U`? ¿Y si resulta que no se puede convertir `U` en `T`?

En el caso del tipo de retorno no hay una solución buena y, lamento confirmarte, el tipo de retorno tiene que estar determinado en tiempo de compilación y tu necesitas que dicho tipo se determine en tiempo de ejecución.

Una posibilidad... si puedes trabajar con C++17 es que uses `std::variant`:

```
template<class T, class U>
std::variant<T,U> Min(T const& a, U const& b)
{
  return (a < b)? a : b;
}

int main()
{
  for( int i=4; i<6; i++ )
  {
    auto resultado = Min(i,4.5);

    if( auto intPtr = std::get_if<int>(&resultado) )
    {
      std::cout << *intPtr << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
      auto num = std::get<double>(resultado);
      std::cout << num << '\n';
    }
  }
}
```

Pero ya vemos que su uso no es demasiado amigable... pero funciona.

> ¿cómo se podría crear el operador < para que tenga en cuenta a todos los tipos de dato (class T, class U...)?

La sobrecarga del operador `<` no entraña demasiado misterio:

```
bool operator<(int a,std::string const& b)
{
  return a < b.length();
}

template<class T, class U>
std::variant<T,U> Min(T const& a, U const& b)
{
  if( a < b)
    return a;
  return b;
}

int main()
{
  for( int i=4; i<6; i++ )
  {
    auto resultado = Min(i,std::string("abcde"));

    if( auto intPtr = std::get_if<int>(&resultado) )
    {
      std::cout << *intPtr << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
      auto num = std::get<std::string>(resultado);
      std::cout << num << '\n';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar tan rápido. Entonces si lo he entendido bien si se ponen 3 clases en la definición de template<class ...> se podría indicar una para el resultado, otra para el primer operando y la otra para el segundo. ¿Es esto correcto?

Comment: @adamista sí... pero tendrías que vigilar que tanto `T` como `U` se pueden convertir al tipo de retorno y esa ya es una solución un tanto dependiente de los requisitos

Comment: Gracias @eferion Por otro lado, ¿cómo se podría crear el operador < para que tenga en cuenta a todos los tipos de dato (class T, class U...)?

Comment: El operador que defines se hace para operar con un dato de tipo int y otro string, pero ¿Cómo se podría hacer para dos tipos int, para dos tipos string? ¿Habría que repetir el código para cada uno o se puede hacer de forma genérica?

Comment: @adamista antes de pasar a ese nivel mejora tus conocimientos de C++... Los comparadores entre enteros, por ejemplo vienen integrados en el propio lenguaje. Los que comparan dos `std::string` están implementados en la librería `string`... solo tienes que preocuparte de los casos en los que el compilador se queje porque no encuentre un comparador adecuado

Comment: Ok, pero por ejemplo en el caso de que se quiera operar con un doublé y un string, ¿Habría que escribir otro operador además del int para que funcionase con ambos tipos?

Comment: @adamista necesitas sobrecargar una vez más el operador para que pueda comparar un `double` y la cadena